# DataTables not formatting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am loading table data from a PHP script. However, once it is loaded, the table doesnt format. It just is a list of the entire table vs a list separated by every 10, 25, etc. I thought that it was possible happening because the datatables call was loading before the php script was done, so I put it in a function to wait for the php call to finish. However, that did not solve the problem.

Here is my jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when($('.test').load('inc/UserTest.php')).done(function() {
        $("#users").dataTable();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use the DataTable's [ajax](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) function to load the data into the table from an other place?

Comment: I am adding columns to the table that are not in the JSON object.

Comment: Do not understand you. So you have a table (DataTable) on your site, filled with some data. After you want to load the .php file, read the data from it, and put it in the table?

Comment: where is this `#users` located? inside `inc/UserTest.php`?

Comment: @Se0ng11 no it is located on the current page where this jQuery resides.

Comment: @NagyVilmos the php file that I would be loading would have 3 columns on a table, whereas I need 4 columns (this column is the same data for every row). I want to load this php file into a table, then apply dataTables to it so that it is formatted nicely.

Comment: @RyanSalmons: It would be so much easier, if you could show us, where you want to put the data (the table before the .DataTable() call), and what do you want to put into the table. (The response of the called page)...